# Two different classes or one with unused properties

Tags: c#, linq, software-design

I'm developing an Augmented Reality for Windows Phone 8.

This app will have a database, and I'm using Linq-to-SQL to create it. This is the table that will have the app:

```
[Table]
public class ARLocation : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    [Column(DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int ARLocationId { get; private set; }

    private string name;
    private string description;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    [Column]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging();
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }    
        }
    }

    [Column]
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging();
                description = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [Column]
    public double Latitude
    {
        get
        {
            return latitude;
        }
        set
        {
            if (latitude != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging();
                latitude = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [Column]
    public double Longitude
    {
        get
        {
            return longitude;
        }
        set
        {
            if (longitude != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging();
                longitude = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var propertyChangedCopy = PropertyChanged; 
        if (propertyChangedCopy != null)
        {
            propertyChangedCopy(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanging([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var propertyChangingCopy = PropertyChanging;
        if (propertyChangingCopy != null)
        {
            propertyChangingCopy(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

But to show that data I will need another column, called `Distance`.

*This is a software design question*:

**Do I need two classes or maybe I can add that column to ARLocation class although I don't use it on my database?**

Answer (score 0):

If you need a function or a property that calculates a value then it is safe to add it to your model class.

If you need to store something extra, a temporary value that you don't really need to save it at the DB then you may want to use partial classes for this. This will keep your model clean and tidy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't understand why to use partial classes. I thought to use inheritance in a new class.

Comment: Partial class will add some more functionality to that particular class only. So at the compile time it will treat as single file only.

Comment: Yes, but, will I have a Distance column on my database if I create a partial class? Maybe I can omit `[Column]` on `Distance` property.

Comment: That is right, you can omit `[Column]` at the new property and it will not be associated with a column at the DB